# Modeling an event Sink in RxJava for events that need onComplete/onError

Tags: java, client, rx-java, event-stream

I'm in the process of writing a client for Apache Mesos' new HTTP Scheduler API using RxJava and RxNetty.

I've managed to successfully create the connection with RxNetty and create an `Observable<Event>` from the resulting chunked stream.

Now I'm at the point of trying to model a sink that can be used to send calls back to Mesos in order to claim/decline resource offers, acknowledge task status updates, etc.

The message that will be sent to sent to Mesos is a `Call`, I need to be able to provide an `onCompleted` or `onError` for every `Call` that comes into the Sink. This is due to Mesos performing synchronous validation on the `Call` being sent to it.

I'm essentially trying to allow for the following:

```
final MesosSchedulerClient client = new MesosSchedulerClient();
final Observable<Event> events = client.openEventStream(subscribeCall);

final Observable<Observable<Call>> ackCalls = events
    .filter(event -> event.getType() == Event.Type.UPDATE && event.getUpdate().getStatus().hasUuid())
    .zipWith(frameworkIDObservable, (Event e, AtomicReference<FrameworkID>> fwId) -> {
        final TaskStatus status = e.getUpdate().getStatus();
        final Call ackCall = ackUpdate(fwId.get(), status.getUuid(), status.getAgentId(), status.getTaskId());
        return Observable.just(ackCall)
            .doOnComplete(() -> { ... })
            .doOnError((e) -> { ... });
    });

client.sink(ackCalls);
```

Right now I've come up with a custom object[1] that extends Subject and specifies the `Call` and `Action0` for `onCompleted` and `Action1<Throwable>` for `onError`.  Though, I would prefer to use the existing constructs from RxJava if possible. Sample usage of what I've come up with[2].

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[1] https://github.com/BenWhitehead/mesos-rxjava/blob/sink-operation/mesos-rxjava-core/src/main/java/org/apache/mesos/rx/java/SinkOperation.java#L17

[2] https://github.com/BenWhitehead/mesos-rxjava/blob/sink-operation/mesos-rxjava-example/mesos-rxjava-example-framework/src/main/java/org/apache/mesos/rx/java/example/framework/sleepy/Main.java#L117-L124

Comment: I'm not familiar with mesos and don't fully understand what you want to achieve. Extending Subject seems to be unnecessary as you don't take subscribers; instead, you may want to use Subscribers.create() or extend Subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @akarnokd I'll investigate creating a Subscriber.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd I switched to using a Subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with was to create a custom Subscriber that would process the event stream and send the requests back to mesos.